# How can i replace in console application image file format with the same file name but different format?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The original format in this case is `.jpg` and I want to replace the files with `.gif`.
So if the original file for example is: `test.jpg`, in the end there will be only `test.gif` in the directory.

This is what I did:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConvertImagesFormats
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileInfo[] imagesToConvert;
            string sourceDirectory = @"C:\test";
            string targetDirectory = @"C:\test";
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory);
            imagesToConvert = di.GetFiles("*.jpg");
            Bitmap bmp;

            for (int i = imagesToConvert.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                bmp = new Bitmap(imagesToConvert[i].FullName);
                bmp.Save(targetDirectory + "\\" + imagesToConvert[i].Name, 
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i'm getting exception on:

```
bmp.Save(targetDirectory + "\\" + imagesToConvert[i].Name, 
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

.

> ExternalException
>
> A generic error occurred in GDI+
>
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2147467259   Message=A generic error occurred in GDI+.
>   Source=System.Drawing   ErrorCode=-2147467259   StackTrace:
>          at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
>          at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
>          at ConvertImagesFormats.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\C-Sharp\ConvertImagesFormats\ConvertImagesFormats\ConvertImagesFormats\Program.cs:line
>   25
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

Comment: it should not be an issue but rule out path issues building the destination file path with `System.IO.Path.Combine` instead of string concatenation

Comment: This is just a simple observation, but you are trying to overwrite the files without changing the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it works? A little refactoring is also added:

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConvertImagesFormats
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sourceDirectory = @"C:\test";
            string targetDirectory = @"C:\test";
            ImageFormat imageFormat = ImageFormat.Gif;

            foreach(var image in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.jpg"))
            {
                using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image))
                {
                    string targetName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(image) + "." + imageFormat;
                    bmp.Save(Path.Combine(targetDirectory, targetName), imageFormat);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @HorheElFenenado you cannot have a `.gif` file with `.jpg` extension. You can delete all files processed if you will.